# Use "Swift Macro" (from Swift 5.9) to declare class, struct, protocol and etc. names?

Tags: swift, macros, swift-macro

In Objective-C we could write something like `#define A B` and replace all "B" occurrences with "A" independently on their meaning.

Now in Swift 5.9 Apple introduced Swift Macro (which adds advanced tools to work with macros) but there is too little information about it and I found how to use this technology with plain strings only:

```
@freestanding(expression)
public macro stringify() -> String = #externalMacro(module: "SomeMacroMacros", type: "StringifyMacro")

public struct StringifyMacro: ExpressionMacro {
    public static func expansion(
        of node: some FreestandingMacroExpansionSyntax,
        in context: some MacroExpansionContext
    ) -> ExprSyntax {
        "\"Test\""
}

print(#stringify) //outputs "Test"
```

But what to do if I want to replace class, struct, protocol names declarations? Is it possible in general with Swift Macro?

**Example**

The following code doesn't work. I just use it to explain what I need to achieve with Swift Macro:

```
#define SomeClass SomeAnotherClass

class SomeClass {
  ...
}
```

Comment: _"But what to do if I want to replace class, struct, protocol names declarations? Is it possible in general with Swift Macro?"_ Please be more specific in what is it that you are trying to achieve? Showing with examples the code which you want to apply your macro to and then the code you want the macro to generate will also help readers understand your requirements.

Comment: Can you clarify your use case a bit more? It sounds to me like you're just looking for `typealias`.

Comment: It's not possible for a macro to replace anything. Swift macros are purely *additive*. You can however have a freestanding macro evaluate to something, but you can't outright modify existing code in-place.

Comment: @tomerpacific and? You just posted a link to official docs which I have already read and don't see any additional info related to my question

Comment: @Gargo - The comment reads: does this help. Not this will be the solution you are looking for. Usually it is customary to show a bit of appreciation when someone tries to help. Also, I have no idea what you read and didn't read. Clearly from the comments, information is missing.

Comment: @DávidPásztor added an example. Hope it is clearer now

Comment: @tomerpacific in my opinion it looks like: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81389/when-should-you-decide-whether-to-flag-a-posted-answer-as-not-an-answer/81392#81392 `'answers' that do not attempt to answer the question`

Comment: @Gargo - I posted a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @Alexander As I understand typealias is a function that gives a new name, or an alias, to an existing type. When you declare macro it doesn't add new swift entities - it just replaces some chunks of code with other chunks. According to this video https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2023/10167/ even if you declare your own macro like a function in the final code it works similarly to usual macros like `#define` - replaces chunks of code.

Comment: @Gargo this seems like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info). Why do you want to replace a type name with another type name at the declaration level? Why does it make sense to declare `class Someclass` instead of `class SomeAnotherClass`? It seems like you expect Swift macros to work like C macros, which literally just substitute some code with some other code. That's not how Swift macros work. As previously stated by others, Swift macros are purely additive, they never replace any code.

Comment: @DávidPásztor I want to declare a list of such macros in a single file and so have a possibility to rename them in a single place.

Comment: @Gargo you should consider the comments more closely. Macros don’t do what you think they do. Rather than your interpretation of a misguided solution approach, you should share your actual underlying issue. From what you’ve just said, I’m 99% sure that type aliases are what you’re looking.

Comment: If these new macro features doesn't allow to do that then it is the answer. Typealias just adds a synonym for existing entity and leaves that original entity unchanged while with macro you could edit the original entity name by editing macro definition. So typealias is not acceptable for my situation.